Prove the transfer between roll. pitch, yaw to tilt, azimuth, swing
I have a paper that explain the transfer between yaw, pitch, roll to the form of tilt swing, azimuth. The paper
I need to prove that the following equations (from the paper) are true:

Pitch first, then roll around "original" or vehicle-axis.\begin{align}\cos t&=\cos\phi\,\cos\omega\\\tan\alpha'&=\frac{\sin\omega}{\tan\phi}\\\tan s&=\frac{\tan\omega}{\sin\phi}\end{align}


How could I prove that this is the right transfer? How did they get these equations?
